# ReadOnlyCollection<T> implements IList<T> but doesn't implement add method

Tags: .net

How is it that `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<T>` implements `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>` but doesn't implement its `Add` method?

I'm not asking *why* it doesn't have an `Add` method -- that's obvious, because it's supposed to be read-only;  I'm asking *how* it can get away without implementing the method, which is required by the `IList<T>` interface contract.

Comment: @Julián Urbano -- I discarded your edits.  In my opinion, the question's title should be title case, and also it's not your place to add content to my question.

Comment: @roryap merely tried to clarify that the method *is* implemented, so it doesn't "get away without implementing the method"; it's just not publicly accessible. As for the title case, I disagree since this is a highly case-sensitive site (see here too http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/capitalizing-titles ). But hey, it's Friday, go nuts.

Comment: @JuliánUrbano -- But the method doesn't appear to be implemented.  I'm getting the compiler error `'a' is not a member of 'b'` whereas if I were to call a method that *was* implemented but just private, I'd get the compiler error `'a' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Private'`.

Comment: Because the method is not `ReadOnlyCollection<T>.Add`, but `IList<T>.Add`. If you cast to `IList<T>` then you can call it (with the exception thrown)

Comment: @JuliánUrbano -- I understand that the method is `IList<T>.Add`, but if it's NOT implemented by `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, then **where is the code located that throws the exception?**

Comment: Man, cool down a bit. They told you in the answers already. It is explicitly implemented in `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. See here for instance, line 88 is where the exception is thrown http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/ObjectModel/ReadOnlyCollection@cs/1305376/ReadOnlyCollection@cs

Comment: @JuliánUrbano -- The bold text was just for emphasis, not to impart emotion.  At any rate, I've read the answers.  I've realized (by testing with both C# and VB) that the source of my confusion stems from the different ways that interfaces work in C# compared to VB.  I have a strong background in VB, and not so much (as you probably guessed) in C#.  In VB, there is no such thing as an implicit interface implementation, and furthermore, even if you implement the method and set its access to `Private`, you can still detect its presence in the way I stated.  This seems not to be the case in C#.

Comment: Yep, it can indeed be tricky. I got myself a few WTFs with this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It explicitly implements the method, along with several others that would generally alter the underlying collection. See the section **Explicit Interface Implementations** on the following page:

[`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx)

The remarks section of the `Add` method indicates why they used an explicit implementation:

> This member is an explicit interface member implementation. It can be used only when the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` instance is cast to an `ICollection<T>` interface.

As a result, developers are prevented from calling the `Add` method directly on an instance of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` (which wouldn't make sense anyway). Explicit interface implementations are frequently used when the implementation of an interface method would always throw an exception due to additional constraints placed on the implementing class (in this case, the object is read-only).

For more information, see the page [**Explicit Interface Implementation (C# Programming Guide)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)

---

**Bonus use case:**

Another place where I use explicit interface implementations is when the implementation of the interface method is overly complex, and derived types might introduce an error in the logic. For example, consider the complex implementation of `IOleCommandTarget.QueryStatus` here [(reference source)](https://github.com/sharwell/vsbase/blob/0f439d26f2f90ec9d70aefa60ce2436e345d92b0/Shell.Utility/CommandFilter.cs#L286-L309). *This code is all boiler-plate code only for the purpose of correct behavior. It does not actually provide the status of any commands.*

```
/// <inheritdoc/>
int IOleCommandTarget.QueryStatus(ref Guid guidCmdGroup, uint cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
{
    using (OleCommandText oleCommandText = OleCommandText.FromQueryStatus(pCmdText))
    {
        Guid cmdGroup = guidCmdGroup;
        for (uint i = 0; i < cCmds; i++)
        {
            OLECMDF status = QueryCommandStatus(ref cmdGroup, prgCmds[i].cmdID, oleCommandText);
            if (status == default(OLECMDF) && _next != null)
            {
                int hr = _next.QueryStatus(ref cmdGroup, cCmds, prgCmds, pCmdText);
                if (ErrorHandler.Failed(hr))
                    return hr;
            }
            else
            {
                prgCmds[i].cmdf = (uint)status;
            }
        }

        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }
}
```

My exposing the following simpler method as `protected virtual` instead of just making the interface method `public virtual`, derived types don't need to worry about properly interpreting the `pCmdText` parameter or how to handle `_next` for each of the items in `prgCmds` [(reference source)](https://github.com/sharwell/vsbase/blob/0f439d26f2f90ec9d70aefa60ce2436e345d92b0/Shell.Utility/CommandFilter.cs#L240-L253).

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the current status of a particular command.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The base implementation returns 0 for all commands, indicating the command is
/// not supported by this command filter.
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="commandGroup">The command group.</param>
/// <param name="commandId">The command ID.</param>
/// <param name="oleCommandText">A wrapper around the <see cref="OLECMDTEXT"/>
/// object passed to <see cref="IOleCommandTarget.QueryStatus"/>, or
/// <see langword="null"/> if this parameter should be ignored.</param>
/// <returns>A collection of <see cref="OLECMDF"/> flags indicating the current
/// status of a particular command, or 0 if the command is not supported by the
/// current command filter.</returns>
protected virtual OLECMDF QueryCommandStatus(ref Guid commandGroup, uint commandId, OleCommandText oleCommandText)
{
    return default(OLECMDF);
}
```

Comment: As I commented to @Crono, I don't understand how, if you try to call a private method on a class, you get a compiler error `'<method>' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Private'` but in this class, I'm getting `'add' is not a member of 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection'`

Answer (score 2):

It's implemented in this way:

```
int IList.Add(object value)
{
    ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(ExceptionResource.NotSupported_ReadOnlyCollection);
    return -1;
}
```

It's also documented at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb347375%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Adds an item to the IList. This implementation always throws NotSupportedException.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `ReadOnlyCollection<>` implementation, one can see that the `Add` method is implemented like this:

```
int IList.Add(object value)
{
    ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(ExceptionResource.NotSupported_ReadOnlyCollection);
    return -1;
}
```

As you can see it's actually an [explicit implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) of `IList.Add` method. This explains why the `Add` method isn't available directly out of `ReadOnlyCollection<>`. If you cast the value to `IList` then you *will* be able to call it, but that will always result into a `NotSupportedException` being thrown.

Notice that other `IList` methods such as `Clear`, `Insert` and `Remove` are also implemented in a similar way in this class, as well as some of the methods of `ICollection<>` too: they're explicitly implemented and throws back exceptions.

Starting from .NET 4.5 the `System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<>` now exists. While the `ReadOnlyCollection<>` class implements it, it still keeps on implementing `IList`, which I guess would be for retrocompatibility reasons. Still, if you are using 4.5 and think of making your own implementation of a readonly collection, **I would advise that you don't implement `IList` and use `IReadOnlyCollection<>` instead**.

Comment: Except that if you try to call `Add`, you get a compiler error indicating that the method does not exist.

Comment: @roryap Yes because as you can see it's implemented explicitely as a private method. This means that while you *can* cast the object as an `IList<>` object, calling the casted result's `Add` method will be possible. Only it will throw an exception.

Comment: @roryap I added more details in my answer, have a look.

Comment: One thing I can't come to terms with is the explicit implementation as a private method.  If you try to call a private method on a class, you get a compiler error `'<method>' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Private'` but in this class, I'm getting ''add' is not a member of 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection'`

Comment: @roryap Granted, it's kind of hard to wrap your mind around it at first, but it actually does make sense in this context. I suggest that you read the documentation on explicit implementation. I provided the link in my answer.